# How to use Jquery Ajax request to load a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I Have an index page which load all the appointments booked on that day..

```
def index
  @appointments = Appointment.where(appointment_date: Date.today, is_deleted: false)
end
```

I have a date_field in the index page which can be used to select a date..

```
<%= date_field 'apppointment','booking_date' , class: 'appointment_booked_date' %>
```

and in my script i made an ajax call like this

```
$('#apppointment_booking_date').on('change', function() {
    selected_date = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        url : '/appointments/show_bookings',
        type : 'GET',
        data : {
            selected_date : selected_date
        },
        success : function(response) {
            console.log("aaa");
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

and in my controller

```
def show_bookings
    @appointments = Appointment.where(appointment_date: params[:selected_date], is_deleted: false)   
end
```

but i dont know how to reload this page..so that i can update the @appointments value in my index page.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **but i dont know how to reload this page**

You don't need to *reload* the page - you send back a response to the original [XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) (Ajax) request. This can be handled with the [`respond_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to) code block:

```
#app/controllers/appointments_controller.rb
Class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
   def show_bookings
      @appointment = ...
      respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.js #-> loads views/appointments/show_bookings.js.erb
      end
   end
end
```

This will allow you to load the `show_bookings.js.erb` file - allowing you to append the code required to make it work (as since it's `erb`, it will have the `@instance variables` available etc):

```
#app/views/appointments/show_bookings.js.erb
alert ("<%=j @appointments %>");
```

---

[**respond_with**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_with)

You'll also be able to use `respond_with`. This is a much DRYer technique:

```
#app/controllers/appointments_controller.rb
Class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :json, :html

   def show_bookings
       @appointments = ...
       respond_with @appointments
   end
end
```

---

**Ajax**

In terms of "capturing" the response from Ajax, you'll want to look at the [`success` callback](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) of your JQuery ajax handler:

```
$('#apppointment_booking_date').on('change', function() {
    selected_date = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        url : '/appointments/show_bookings',
        type : 'GET',
        data : {
            selected_date : selected_date
        },
        success : function(response) {
            alert(response); #-> "console.log" doesn't work for us in Rails
        }
    });
});
```

The "response" you receive will be dependent on the `respond_to` or `respond_with` blocks you use. Either one will give you the ability to use the returned data in your application